# Importing from Oracle to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle10g

I am trying to import a table from Oracle into SQL server 2008 using .net of the SQL import/export wizard, the table contains 2 million records and when it reaches 35000 it failed and generate the following error:

> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Source -
>   PORTRAIT" (1)" failed because error code 0x80004003 occurred, and the
>   error row disposition on "output column "IMAGE_DATA" (70)" specifies
>   failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the
>   specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.
>
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc02090f5: Data Flow Task 1: The component "Source - PORTRAIT"
>   (1) was unable to process the data. Pipeline component has returned
>   HRESULT error code 0xC0209029 from a method call.
>
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source
>   - PORTRAIT" (1) returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I need to know why it failed.

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076765/importing-from-oracle-to-sql-server

Comment: in the previous one it was stopping before starting the importing, now it starts importing but stops at record 35000, and it generate a different error. this is the difference

Comment: OK. But please remember that you are importing into **SQL Server** not to *SQL* (SQL is a language)

Comment: "There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure"..  Are there any?

Comment: Tom Hunter: no there is no previous errors, it just show this error in the report

Answer (score 0):

Check your data types. Specifically for the IMAGE_DATA data type. Either the source and destination don't match properly, you haven't specified the right data type during the transform, etc.

The error you are getting is around the transformation and it is barking at a data type. What is the source data type and size/precision/etc. What is the destination's? Look there more.

Comment: I am leaving SQL server to create the destination table, Im not creating it

Comment: That doesn't change the point of my answer. It doesn't always create the table right. What are the data types?